# Canadian PR had US visa refused after US deportation and ban

Tags: visas, usa

I'm a Canadian Permanent Resident. I illegally entered the USA 13 years ago, and was deported back to Canada with a 10 year ban.

Now it has been 13 years. I applied for a US B1 visa; I'm a truck driver now and need to cross the border for work.

I went to my interview today. The officer asked me about what happened and I told him everything: the truth that I was young and made a mistake I regret everyday now. I'm 40 years old and have been straight and need this for work. He made some notes and said "I have to refuse your visa. But you will get email within the next few days; we want to have  another  interview with you within this week, and will see then what we can do."

Does anyone know how will this play out for me ?

Comment: @L G I have edited your question to enhance its readability, and tried to maintain its content. If you think I have changed what you meant to say, you can (using the "edit" button below the question) roll back my edits so the question appears as you originally posted it.

Comment: It sounds like you may be inadmissible for some reason in addition to the (now expired) ban and that the consular officer is minded to recommend a waiver.

Comment: I agree with phoog. That they did not deny your application right away is a good sign. There's nothing to do now but watch your email, show up for the second interview, and continue to tell the truth. Good luck!